# Same website but different SSL/TLS Certificate public-key in chrome than it in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I try to connect to a website using chrome vs, firefox. I should get the same public-key value but this is not the case. I get diffrent public-key in each browser. Can anyone explain why?
Here is what I get in firefox:

[image]

Here is what I get in Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Are you showing the same final certificate? In Firefox the window shows 'Niagara ax' and in chrome subject and issuer start with the same string

Comment: I suspect that both certificates are the same. The problem is how each broweser present the certificate to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, both browsers show the same public key. The difference is in public key presentation in these dialogs. Firefox displays only modulus value, while Chrome displays entire ASN.1-encoded public key with outer `SEQUENCE` tag, modulus and with public exponent at the end (`01 00 01`). Here is ASN.1 definition of public key:

```
RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
    modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
    publicExponent    INTEGER   -- e
}
```

Chrome displays entire type, Firefox displays only `modulus` field.

Comment: I have checked it with an ASN.1 editor in other site and you're right (+1). In fact you can see that the starting hex of firefox `b4 2d 2e 65` are present in chrome from position 8